# How to make a table column an average of two other columns

Tags: mysql, database, formula

Is there a way that I could make the column type an equation of two other columns?
Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_leaderboard` (
    `leaderboardID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `totalScore` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `gamesPlayed` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `averageScore` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `player_score` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `userID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `playerID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`leaderboardID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `tbl_user`(`userID`)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`playerID`) REFERENCES `tbl_player`(`playerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I would like `averageScore` to equal `totalscore/gamesPlayed`. Is it possible to make the column type work like this, or does it only work on the insert statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's called `computed column` or `generated column` feature:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_leaderboard` (
    `leaderboardID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `totalScore` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `gamesPlayed` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `averageScore` DOUBLE as (totalscore /gamesPlayed) ,
    `player_score` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `userID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `playerID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`leaderboardID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `tbl_user`(`userID`)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`playerID`) REFERENCES `tbl_player`(`playerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and you don;t have to mention it in your update/insert statements , since it automatically will be calculated based on other columns

Comment: Yup, that is it. @Travis123